# Create folder on OneDrive with API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to create new folder on OneDrive through API, but I am getting Exception

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException' with message 'Must provide one of the following facets to create an item: Bundle, File, Folder, RemoteItem

This is with `$a = ["name" => "Folder"];`.

If I change it to this:

```
$a = ["name" => "Folder", "folder" => array()];
$this->provider->post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children',$a,$_SESSION['access_token']);
```

Then I get

> Property folder in payload has a value that does not match schema

From the [example page](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/create.htm) I am assuming that `folder` value should be empty array.

Comment: Can you post the JSON from the body of the POST? I'm concerned that the empty array isn't being included in the actual POST body.

Comment: I already solved the problem, but I don't understand why in [docs](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/create.htm) in EXAMPLE is JSON `folder` parameter empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct format for the folder was
`$folderParameters = ["name" => $folderName, "folder" => ["childCount" => '0']];`

Comment: In Swift this is the format that worked for me. `["name" : "FolderName", "folder" : ["childCount" : "0"]] as [String : Any]`