# create folder with microsoft graph api

Tags: php, json, microsoft-graph-api

I'm try to create folder, using microsoft graph API. In microsoft graph explorer, all work fine, but my php code return an error:

```
$name = 'newFolder'; $access_token = '123..';
$link = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children';

$data = array(
    "name" => $name,
    "folder" => array()
);

$curl=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$link);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token, 'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);

$out = curl_exec($curl);
$codeCurl = curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
```

this is response of '$out': *400 BadRequest, Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format*. I'm can't understand, what wrong? json data is correct, headers too..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [microsoft graph API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0) shows this example request for create folder:

```
POST /me/drive/root/children
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "New Folder",
  "folder": { },
  "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename"
}
```

To get this part of the request :  `"folder": { }` you could either put `"folder" => new stdClass()` in your $data array or keep this `"folder" => array()` and use `json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`. If you use JSON_FORCE_OBJECT, all arrays will be encoded as objects.
I had the same problem, but error in the response was a bit different: *Property folder in payload has a value that does not match schema*. I am using `"folder" => new stdClass()` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is using "json_encode()" to put data in a right format. And correct format for the folder was `$folderParameters = ["name" => $name, "folder" => ["childCount" => '0']];` (thank [Create folder on OneDrive with API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270392/create-folder-on-onedrive-with-api))

The right code is :

```
$link = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children';

$data = [
    "name"   => $name,
    "folder" => ["childCount" => '0']
];

$headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
];

$curl=curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$link);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);

$out = curl_exec($curl); 
$codeCurl = curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
```